# How to use shopify polaris css components?

Tags: shopify, polaris

I want to use Polaris css components for my shopify app. I have go through their document https://polaris.shopify.com/components/get-started#navigation. As mentioned there I have include their css and html code for a component but some components are not working functionally like Date picker I have put html code on my page but I am not able to change month, select date etc.

I think I have to load js for get that working but I didn't found any js link in their document.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: From my knowledge, Shopify components are built using React, so you're definitely going to need javascript in order to get them working correctly the way you want. Have you forked their repository to get them initially working on your machine? 

source: https://github.com/Shopify/polaris

Comment: @RyanGreen thanks for reply. I have tried using react also but there also I have to write logic for collapse etc effect there is no bult-in js like bootstrap js.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the CSS-only version, we do not provide any JS. The CSS version is meant for someone who does not want to use React and is willing to write the scripts required for any interactive components. If you are using the React components, you will not find everything; as you've identified, this is not exactly like Bootstrap or similar frameworks. This is a more selective set of components that encompass patterns that have been established for Shopify's own applications. We will probably add more components in the future, though; if there's something you feel is obviously missing, please feel free to leave an issue.

Comment: Where is the documentation for the CSS only system?

Comment: @Will Exactly. It is missing. I'm looking all over their documents but to no avail.